# How can we calculate the limit at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Suppose we have the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 
x\cdot (-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]} & x\neq 0\\ 
0 & x=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I want to show that $g$ is continuous at $0$ and discontinuous at $\frac{1}{2}$.

How can we calculate the limit at $0$ ?

Comment: What are the square brackets?

Comment: The integer part. @Daniel

Answer (score 3):

For $x\in(\frac13,\frac12]$, $\lfloor \frac1x\rfloor=2$, and for $x\in(\frac12,1]$, $\lfloor \frac1x\rfloor=1$.

Then $$x\in(\frac13\frac12]\implies f(x)=x,\\
x\in(\frac12,1]\implies f(x)=-x.$$

This is enough to conclude about the continuity at $\frac12$ (compare the left and right limits).

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

To see the continuity at $0$, use the Squeeze theorem:

$$-1\leq(-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]}\leq1$$

$$\Rightarrow -x\leq x\cdot(-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]}\leq x$$

To see the discontinuity, try find two sequences of real numbers, $x_i, y_i$ that both converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ but $$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} f(x_i) \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(y_i)$$

Comment: Ahh I see... So, for $x=0$ we get that $x\cdot (-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]}=0$, right? I want to show also that the function is discontinuous at $\frac{1}{2}$. Do we use agian the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes, that is right. To see the discontinuity, try find two sequences of real numbers, $x_i, y_i$ that both converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ but $$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} f(x_i) \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(y_i)$$

Comment: I see... Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since we are trying to show that the limit in 0 is zero, we can analyze the absolute value of the function. Thus:
$$
lim_{x\to 0}|g(x)|=lim_{x\to 0}|x\cdot (-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]}|=lim_{x\to 0}|x| = 0 = g(0)
$$

Comment: Ah ok... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer tells you why it's continuous at 0: the $x$ term is squashing everything down to 0, so any discontinuities are being squeezed away.

Discontinuous at 1/2: it's enough to find two sequences tending to 1/2 such that $g$ tends to two different values along the sequences. We can in fact pick one sequence $x_i \to \frac{1}{2}$ such that every term $g(x_i)$ is positive, and another sequence such that every term is negative, and such that neither sequence is tending to zero.

Comment: Can we use the sequences $$x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2} , \ \ y_n=-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2}$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yep, that works :)

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-)